# Как сделать картинку адаптивной?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
background-size: contain
 max-width: 100%
```

```html
<div class="d">
  <img src="img/picture-glav.png" alt="доктор" class="doc">
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы картинка была на всю секцию и адаптивной ?`

```css
.d
 margin-left: 25%
 background-size: contain
 max-width: 100%
```

```html
<div class="d">
  <img src="img/picture-glav.png" alt="доктор" class="doc">
</div>
```

`

Comment: Похоже, что вам нужно свойство [object-fit](https://webref.ru/css/object-fit), а не `background-size`

Comment: Deonis  а как его используют ?

Comment: По ссылке есть примеры.

Comment: спасибо большое хоть кто откликнулся

Comment: Deonis а можно еще спросить ?

Comment: Для этого не нужно чьё-то разрешение )) Вы спрашивайте, а тот кто может и знает - ответит.

Comment: Deonis я добавил еще 1 картинку чтобы она сработа достаточно прописать атрибут download ?

Comment: `.d { background: url(img/picture-glav.png) center no-repeat; background-size:cover; } .d img {display:none; }`

Comment: спасибо брооооо